# Creating my own strcopy function

Tags: c++

I am trying to create my own str copy function. I get an error telling me strcopy was not declated in this scope 
strcopy(deck[i].suit,source[]); is wehre my error occurs. help please!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct{
char suit[];
char rank[];
int cvalue;
};
int main()
{
char source[] = "name";
cards deck[52];

strcopy(deck[].suit,source[]);
}

void strcopy(char destination[], char source[])
{
for(int i=0; source[i] != '\0' && destination[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
destination[i] = source[i];
}
}
```

Comment: the compiler error is correct. `strcopy` is not declared at the point where you try to use it. It is declared *afterwards, but the C++ compiler is naive, it needs to know that the function exists at the point where it is called.

Comment: please google your error at least.

Comment: thanks for all your help guys, im learning to code so i do make some novice mistakes.

@djechlin, go get some exercise or something. theres really no need to hide behind your computer and be rude

Comment: Okay, let's try this again. I've voted to close your question and you have two downvotes. Most of your other questions have between -1 and 0 downvotes. If you continue to post questions of this quality you will be banned from asking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you forgot to specify the name of the structure. I think it should have name `cards`

Also arrays defined within the structure have to be defined as having sizes.

```
struct{
char suit[];  // What is the size of the array?
char rank[];  // What is the size of the array?
int cvalue;
};
```

Function `strcopy` has to be declared before its isage.

And the function itself is wrong.

I would not invent a new algorithm of the function and write it the following way

```
char * strcopy( char destination[], const char source[] )
{
   char *p = destination;

   while ( *p++ = *source++ );

   return destination; 
}
```

Comment: i retyped it, im posting on my real computer and programming in virutal box and its easier that way, must have left cards out. i specified values in the arrays. What is the matter with my action function?

Comment: @jalf  The function has no sense. First of all it will copy nothing if the destination array starts with zero and it does not copy the terminating zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using 'strcopy' function before your compiler knows that there is one. In C/C++ you have to either define it on top or provide information that there is one by providing protoype of the function.

So either move it like so:

```
void strcopy(char destination[], char source[])
{
    for(int i=0; source[i] != '\0' && destination[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = source[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    char source[] = "name";
    cards deck[52];

    strcopy(deck[].suit,source[]);
}
```

or add protoype before using it:

```
void strcopy(char destination[], char source[]);

int main()
{
    char source[] = "name";
    cards deck[52];

    strcopy(deck[].suit,source[]);
}

void strcopy(char destination[], char source[])
{
   for(int i=0; source[i] != '\0' && destination[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
       destination[i] = source[i];
   }
}
```

For more information you can see it on wiki too:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype

I also structured your code for better readability ;)